# Woocommerce template override not working with woocommerce.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a template file with customisations driving a woocommerce site, and recently updated to Woocommerce 2.1.2.

The problem is that the changes made to the inserted myTemplate/woocommerce/archive-product.php are not functioning, only when I delete woocommerce.php, but then all my previous customisations are lost

I have the code in my woocommerce.php, as suggested

```
<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
```

And added support in my function.php like this:

```
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
```

The other template files eg. woocommerce/content-single-product.php seem to work with the changes I make to them...

Is it because the update to v2? How can it be fixed that my customisations are working?

Also, I tried copying the archive-product.php to plugins/woocommerce folder, but it seems it is still not using that file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-template-functions.php

Comment the lines like this:

```
if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) 
{

//while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

              wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );

//endwhile;

} else { ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but will it not be lost if I update the Woocommerce plugin?

Comment: Did it work? Actually it is better not to modify the core files, but I don't understand why is looking for posts to show a single product.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't try it, because I did what I want by other way - by hooks in functions.php (it seems that is the way WooCommerce expects the changes to be made). Cheers, g

Comment: A similar problem happens when there's only one product in a category to show. Does anyone know why is that?

Comment: It may be a long shot but maybe this link will help https://colorlib.com/wp/forums/topic/template-overrides-not-working/ .  Hint: read at the end. It helped me. Maybe will help someone else too.